# Is there a way to extract table names from large code base

Tags: vb6, enterprise-architect

I have imported a very large code base into Enterprise Architect ( sparx) and we need to find out what all tables are used in this code base. This code gets run every night and we are porting it to VB.NET core.

I'm trying to find all instances of what tables are used in this code base. going through the code line by line would take a very long time.

Just seeing if there is a simpler way to find out all the tables used in the code base.

Comment: Why do you need to know which tables are used?  Are you trying to clean up / prune the database as well?

Comment: How is the application accessing the database? Is it using ADO? If so you might be able to handle the `ExecuteComplete` event on the ADO Connection object and extract some information from that.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll ever find a "complete" answer, but I would start by searching the whole project for places in SQL statements where you know you'll likely encounter table names..  Things like ` FROM `, ` LEFT JOIN `, etc...  Search for other ways.  Then grab a list with duplicates and put them somewhere such as Excel and get a distinct list.  That's what I would start with, personally, short of any better solution.  Other options would include altering the code to log SQL statements to a text file during execution and inspect those.  There's probably other (better) ways.

Comment: Actually I have no idea what you want. Which tables? And what is that imported code base?